# My test class code coverage is 100 percent but it is giving following error in run

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests

For report event my test class code coverage is 100% but it is giving following error

> System.UnexpectedException: common.exception.SfdcSqlException: We
>   encountered an unexpected error. Contact Salesforce Customer Support.
>   Error ID: 1147465140-62040 (747818029)

Answer (score 1):

A System.UnexpectedException looks like a [gack](https://developer.salesforce.com/blogs/engineering/2015/02/gack.html). This is one you'll need to create a ticket for at help.salesforce.com using the error Id as a reference.

Comment: It's a big object is it possible?